# Extending Non Generic Interface with Generic Interface

Tags: typescript

I'm probably over thinking this.  Basically, I would like to have an non-generic interface that implements a few properties, then create a second type that implements that interface with it's own generic property.

```
interface Car {
  model: string;
}

interface Car<T> extends Car {
  transmission: T;
}
```

TypeScript errors:

> "All declarations of 'Car' must have identical type parameters."

The only way I can find is to name the non-generic interface something different, like CarBase.  Suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why would you separate it into two different interfaces with the same name? It's equivalent to `interface Car<T> { model: string; transmission: T }`

Comment: I want other code to use the non-generic reference.  Currenly Im doing Car<any> to bypass the type checking, when I just want to use Car.

Comment: Why do they have to have the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) to save you the trouble of writing `Car<any>`:

```
interface Car<T> {
    model: string;
    transmission: T;
}

type AnyCar = Car<any>;
```

Comment: Is this just the same as writing:
`interface CarBase implements Car<any>` ?

Comment: It's pretty much the same, but there are differences between interfaces and type aliases. It is explained in [Interfaces vs. Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases)